# Highlight and PopUp multiple country in Datamaps.js

Tags: javascript, datamaps

In Datamaps.js, Could I make it that when the mouse hovers over Germany, Italy also highlights simultaneously and only one popup appears?

https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps